# Why setting window.location.href to session storage item value is considered a DOM XSS vulnerability?

Tags: javascript, security, dom, xss, fortify

Fortify SCA reports that the following code is DOM XSS vulnerable:

```
const returnUrl = sessionStorage.getItem('returnUrl') || '/';
window.location.href = returnUrl;
```

When a user enters my application by clicking a link for example, and the user is not logged in:

1. The app stores `window.location.href` into `returnUrl` item in session storage
2. It sets `window.location.href` to an external login page
3. When the user enter their credentials, the external login page redirects to `logged-in.html` page of my app.
4. `logged-in.html` contains the above code, setting `window.location.href` to the value stored in `returnUrl` item of session storage.

Why is this vulnerable?. How can I mitigate it?

### Edit

I didn't execute Fortify, an external company did it, and reported the following:

```
CWE-80.
Input Validation and
Representation:
Cross-Site Scripting:
DOM
```

Comment: What is the specific error that Fortify SCA reports? Please use copy and paste to add it to the question (with `>` in front so mark it as quoted).

Comment: So, what happens if a script on the page does `sessionStorage.setItem("returnUrl", "theattackerdomain.com")`?

Comment: @VLAZ for that to be possible, my app needs to be successfully attacked first to inject that code. Right?

Comment: I don't know how your app works. Maybe you use external scripts which are already vulnerable, so it doesn't take much for the attack to manifest. Or, who knows, you may have some other XSS vulnerability. Or you don't have one *now* but may have one in the future - 15 months from now, when you would have forgotten about this Fortify report. Ultimately, does it really matter? Clearly, the process is vulnerable to rather basic tampering with the application.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. I din't execute Fortify, an external company did it, and reported the following: CWE-80. Input Validation and Representation: Cross-Site Scripting: DOM

Comment: You should not trust any external data, not even SessionStorage, the data could be spoofed before storing it (also it can be spoofed while storing it in an infected device). That's why you always must validate external data before use.

Comment: @VLAZ. It is an Angular app, it loads all scripts from the web application server, except logedd-in.html that loads https://alcdn.msauth.net/browser/2.22.1/js/msal-browser.min.js. If someone can inject `sessionStorage.setItem("returnUrl", "theattackerdomain.com")` it can also inject  `window.location.href = "theattackerdomain.com"`, so what's the point?

Comment: @Teemu. Thank you. So you are suggesting to validate `returnUrl` value?. I can easily validate the domain and the protocol, but validate the path and query string is very hard, as there are a lot.

Comment: @JesúsLópez ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Well, I guess just don't do any verification, don't take any common sense precautions, and just reinvent how redirection after login is done, then. It might be that *you* found a redirection scheme that all other web applications failed to realise the potential for. They, and Fortify itself, are probably wrong.

Comment: Validating the protocol and domain will be a great help already, it prevents a visitor to navigate to attacker's site.

Comment: @VLAZ. I'm not inventing nothing new. Taking the returnUrl from session storage is exactly what @azure/msal-browser library from Microsoft does. I just need to know why this is vulnerable and how to mitigate it. I cannot remove that feature

Comment: @Teemu. Could you please make your comments as an answer?. Something like: "it is vulnerable because sessionStorage is not trustworthy. The device might be infected and sessionStorage might be spoofed"

Comment: @JesúsLópez That's only a part of the story. It was hard to find the Fortify explanation for this, I managed to find this [Github source](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-fortify/blob/master/sonar-fortify-plugin/src/main/resources/rules/rules-js.xml#L149) only. As raw XML, it's a bit hard to read, but there's the entire explanation for this specific security audit failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I mitigate it?

Don't store a full URL, just store the necessary information (such as a page name, or even an enum-like value that identifies the page to go to). Then, when going back to the page, validate the data from session storage before building a URL from only known values and validated values:

```
const returnInfo = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("returnUrl"));
if (returnInfo && validatePageName(returnInfo.pageName) && /*...*/) {
    window.location.href = "/" + returnInfo.pageName; // Or similar
}
```

...where `validatePageName` ensures that the string passed to it is just the name of a page in your app, and not (for instance) a full URL.

Or if that's too much of a change, at least validate the URL before using it:

```
const returnUrl = new URL(
    sessionStorage.getItem("returnUrl") || "/"),
    location
);
if (
  returnUrl.protocol === location.protocol &&
  returnUrl.port === location.port &&
  returnUrl.hostname === location.hostname &&
  /*...other checks as necessary ...*/
) {
    window.location.href = returnUrl;
}
```